# Hold on callback function execution until promise is completed

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, ecmascript-5

I have some third party library whose events I'm listening. I get a chance to modify data which that library is going to append in the UI. It is all fine until that data modification is synchronous. As soon as I involve Ajax callbacks/promises, this fails to work. Let me put an example to show case the problem.

Below is how I'm listening to a event:-

```
d.on('gotResults', function (data) {

  // If alter data directly it works fine.
  data.title = 'newTitle';
  // Above code alters the text correctly.

  //I want some properties to be grabbed from elsewhere so I make an Ajax call.
  $.ajax('http://someurl...', {data.id}, function (res) {
    data.someProperty = res.thatProperty;
  });
  // Above code doesn't wait for ajax call to complete, it just go away and 
  renders page without data change.


  // Yes I tried promises but doesn't help
  return fetch('http://someurl...').then(function (data) {
    data.someProperty = res.thatProperty;
    return true;
  });
  // Above code also triggers the url and gets away. Doesn't wait for then to complete.

});
```

I cannot change/alter the third party library. All I have is to listen to event and alter that data.

Any better solutions. Nope. I can't use async/wait, generators, because I want to have it supported for ES5 browsers.

Comment: So, your 3rd party library needs a synchronous response, but you only have an asynchronous one? Then you're pretty much stuffed.

Comment: Which library are we talking about? Is it possible to just not to use the builtin result transformation logic and wrap the whole thing with your own code that would handle asynchronousness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make a synchronous function wait for an asynchronous response, it's simply not possible by definition. Your options pretty much are:

1. **BAD IDEA:** Make a *synchronous* AJAX request. Again: **BAD IDEA.** Not only will this block the entire browser, it is also a deprecated practice and should not be used in new code, or indeed ever.
2. Fetch the asynchronous data first and store it locally, so it's available synchronously when needed. That obviously only works if you have an idea what data you'll be needing ahead of time.
3. Alter the 3rd party library to add support for asynchronous callbacks, or request that of the vendor.
4. Find some hackaround where you'll probably let the library work with incomplete data first and then update it when the asynchronous data is available. That obviously depends a lot on the specifics of that library and the task being done.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `gotResults` callback function really need to return anything else than `true`? If not, then you could just write regular asynchronous code without this library knowing about it. Let me explain myself by rewriting your pseudocode:

```js
d.on('gotResults', function (data) {

  // If alter data directly it works fine.
  data.title = 'newTitle';
  // Above code alters the text correctly.

  //I want some properties to be grabbed from elsewhere so I make an Ajax call.
  $.ajax('http://someurl...', {data.id}, function (res) {
    data.someProperty = res.thatProperty;

    // Above code doesn't wait for ajax call to complete, it just go away and 
    // EDIT: now it should render properly
    renders page without data change.


    // Yes I tried promises but doesn't help
    return fetch('http://someurl...');
    // Above code also triggers the url and gets away. Doesn't wait for then to complete.


  }).then(function (data) {
    data.someProperty = res.thatProperty;
    
    // maybe render again here?
  }).catch(function(err) { 
    handleError(err); // handle errors so the don't disappear silently
  });
  return true; // this line runs before any of the above asynchronous code but do we care?
});
```

Comment: The problem here. By the time I have ajax response, library has already done it's job of rendering. So altering any JS objects doesn't do any changes in UI.